# Ayuda par optimizar este codigo

Tags: angular, typescript, optimización

Tanto `skills`, como `resources` y `evaluations` son grupos de `checkboxes` presentes en el HTML, recibo el objeto y lo agrego en un array diferente según el tipo, en el caso que se desmarque lo quito.

LO que quiero hacer es que el código sea lo mas optimo posible, porque como ven todas las funciones hacen lo mismo.

**Component.TS**

```
  evaluationsSelected = [];
  skillsSelected = [];
  resourcesSelected = [];


  clickResources(resource: Resource, isSelected: boolean) {
    if (isSelected) {
      this.resourcesSelected.push({
        name: resource.label,
        reference : this.db.collection('resources').doc(`${resource.id}`).ref
      });
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.resourcesSelected.length; i++) {
        if (this.resourcesSelected[i].name === resource.label) {
          this.resourcesSelected.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  clickEvaluations(evaluation: Evaluation, isSelected: boolean) {
    if (isSelected) {
      this.evaluationsSelected.push({
        name: evaluation.label,
        reference : this.db.collection('evaluations').doc(`${evaluation.id}`).ref
      });
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.evaluationsSelected.length; i++) {
        if (this.evaluationsSelected[i].name === evaluation.label) {
          this.evaluationsSelected.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  clickSkills(skill: Skill, isSelected: boolean) {
      if (isSelected) {
        this.skillsSelected.push({
          name: skill.label,
          reference : this.db.collection('skills').doc(`${skill.id}`).ref
        });
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.evaluationsSelected.length; i++) {
          if (this.skillsSelected[i].name === skill.label) {
            this.skillsSelected.splice(i, 1);
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 Evaluations:
        <div *ngFor= "let evaluation of evaluations">
            <input type="checkbox" name = "evaluations" value="{{evaluation.id}}" (change) = "clickEvaluations(evaluation,$event.target.checked)">{{evaluation.label}}
        </div>
        <br>
        Skills:
        <div *ngFor= "let skill of skills">
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{skill.id}}" (change) = "clickSkills(skill ,$event.target.checked)"> {{skill.label}}
        </div>
        <br>
```

Comment: La verdad que no he entendido tu situación. Te recomiendo aclarecer más qué hace tu código actual, qué quieres lograr y poner un ejemplo de cómo usas tu código actualmente, qué le pasas a esos métodos y nosotros poder ver todo el flujo y ponernos creativos. Debes agregar más contexto a tu pregunta. De igual forma agrega tus interfaces para ver qué tienen y cómo utilizas eso en tus métodos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar union de tipos ya que comparten los mismos atributos. Y pasar tanto los arreglos como el nombre de la coleccion como argumento al metodo

```
clickItem(item: Resource | Evaluation | Skill, isSelected: boolean, arr: any[], colName: string) {
  if (isSelected) {
    arr.push({
      name: item.label,
      reference : this.db.collection(colName).doc(`${item.id}`).ref
    });
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].name === item.label) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ahora bien, ¿es necesario modificar los arreglos con cada click?
Podrias realizar eso en un paso posterior.
Tambien podrias guardar el atributo selected en los mismos tipos de datos Resource, Evaluation y Skill. O agregar un tipo nuevo como:

```
interface Selectable<T> {
  data: T;
  selected: boolean;
  reference: any;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una función genérica que reciba el tipo de modelo y parametrizarla con los datos necesarios. Como los modelos que tienes tienen propiedades comunes puedes hacer lo siguiente.

La función base es la que contiene la lógica para hacer el toggle de los checkboxes.

```
evaluationsSelected = [];
skillsSelected = [];
resourcesSelected = [];

clickResources(resource: Resource, isSelected: boolean) {
    toggleCheckbox<Resource>('resources',this.resourcesSelected, resource, isSelected);
}

clickEvaluations(evaluation: Evaluation, isSelected: boolean) {
    toggleCheckbox<Evaluation>('evaluations', this.evaluationsSelected, evaluation, isSelected);
}

clickSkills(skill: Skill, isSelected: boolean) {
    toggleCheckbox<Skill>('skills', this.skillsSelected, skill, isSelected);
}

toggleCheckbox<T>(colName: string, data: any, item: T, isSelected: boolean) {
    if (isSelected) {
        data.push({
            name: item.label,
            reference : this.db.collection(colName).doc(`${item.id}`).ref
        });
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].name === item.label) {
                data.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: es una buena idea, pero el arreglo data no deberia ser de tipo T

Comment: gracias. porque?

Comment: porque el tipo T es del item: Resource, Skill o Evaluation. Mientras que data tiene elementos con un tipo no relacionado, que posee propiedades name y reference.

Comment: entiendo. Si tienes razón no caí en eso. Lo pongo como any. Gracias man